# Bootstrap col full width without container padding

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two columns in row and i want to make right column align to right side of browser (without container padding) and left column with left side container padding. For now i set width of right element for about 200% but this is not sloution that i want... Is there something better to use to get cool nice and clean?
I want get something like this:

[image]

```css
section {
 background: #000;
 color: #fff;
 height: 1000px;
 padding: 150px 0;
 font-family: Roboto;
}

h1 {
 color: #fff;
 width: 250px;
 font-size: 36px;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 font-weight: 500;
 background-size: 200% 100%;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to right,rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%,#fff 50%);
 -webkit-transition: all .5s;
 -moz-transition: all .5s;
 transition: all .5s;
}

#aboutUs.col-md-7 {
 z-index: 999;
}

#aboutUs p {
 margin-top: 150px;
 font-size: 16px;
 line-height: 1.8em;
 letter-spacing: 1.2px;
 text-align: justify;
 color: #fff;
 border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,.8);
 padding: 20px 30px;
 margin-left: 40px;
 font-weight: 400;
 -webkit-transition: all .5s;
 -moz-transition: all .5s;
 transition: all .5s;
 z-index: 999;
}

.aboutUsfoto {
 background-image: url(https://newevolutiondesigns.com/images/freebies/city-wallpaper-47.jpg);
 border-bottom: 5px solid #fff;
 height: 600px;
 background-position: center;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-size: cover;
 line-height: 600px;
 text-align: center;
 width: 180%;
 margin-left: -140px;
 z-index: -1;
 -webkit-transition: all .5s;
 -moz-transition: all .5s;
 transition: all .5s;
 opacity: .4;
}
```

```html
<section id="aboutUs">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <h1>O nas</h1>
   </div>


   <div class="col-md-7">
    <p class="desc wow bounceInLeft" data-wow-delay=".5s" data-wow-duration=
    "1.2s">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur <b>adipisicing elit</b>, sed
    do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
    minim veniam, <b>quis nostrud exercitation</b> ullamco laboris nisi ut
    aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
    voluptate velit esse cillum <b>dolore eu fugiat</b> nulla pariatur.
    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in <b>culpa qui
    officia</b> deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <a class="btn btn-outline pull-right text-center wow bounceInLeft"
    data-wow-delay=".9s" data-wow-duration="1.2s" href="#">Czytaj więcej</a>
   </div>


   <div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="aboutUsfoto wow bounceInRight" data-wow-delay=".2s"
    data-wow-duration="1.2s">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Comment: _"I want something like this"_ and what have you tried so far? What seems to be the problem?

Comment: "For now i set width of right element for about 200% but this is not sloution that i want..."

Comment: Your image size is bigger than the div col-md-5, is this your problem?

Comment: Doesn't `<div class="row">` remove the padding from the `<div class="col-xx-x">`? You could try and place this in the `col-xx-x` container to remove the padding?

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container

Answer (score 1):

Create these classes in your css:

```
.no-pad-y {padding-left: 0;padding-right:0;}
.no-pad-right {padding-right: 0;}
.no-pad-left {padding-left: 0;}
```

Change HTML to this:

```
<section id="aboutUs">
    <div class="container no-pad-y">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1>O nas</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7 no-pad-left">
                <p class="desc wow bounceInLeft" data-wow-delay=".5s" data-wow-duration="1.2s">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur <b>adipisicing elit</b>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                    Ut enim ad minim veniam, <b>quis nostrud exercitation</b> ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum <b>dolore eu fugiat</b> nulla pariatur.
                    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in <b>culpa qui officia</b> deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline pull-right text-center wow bounceInLeft" data-wow-delay=".9s" data-wow-duration="1.2s">Czytaj więcej</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5 no-pad-right">
                <div class="aboutUsfoto wow bounceInRight" data-wow-delay=".2s" data-wow-duration="1.2s">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: With your solution image is full width on container its not what i want, but thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i found solution.. So i deleted `col-md-5` from right column and add to `.aboutUsfoto` some styles:

```
.aboutUsfoto {
position:absolute;
right:0;
z-index:1;
width:60vw;
}
```

And this is what i want get. Thanks for help guys.

```css
    section {
     background: #000;
     color:#fff;
     height: 1000px;
     padding: 150px 0;
     font-family: Roboto;
    }
    h1 {
      color: #fff;
      width:250px;
      font-size: 36px;
      padding: 10px 20px;
      font-weight:500;
      background-size: 200% 100%;
       background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50%, #fff 50%);
       -webkit-transition: all .5s;
       -moz-transition: all .5s;
       transition: all .5s;
     }

     #aboutUs.col-md-7 {
      z-index: 999;
     }
     #aboutUs p {
      margin-top: 150px;
      font-size: 16px;
      line-height: 1.8em;
      letter-spacing: 1.2px;
      text-align: justify;
      color: #fff;
      border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
      padding: 20px 30px;
      margin-left: 40px;
      font-weight: normal;
       -webkit-transition: all .5s;
       -moz-transition: all .5s;
       transition: all .5s;
      z-index: 999;
     }
     .aboutUsfoto {
       background-image: url(https://newevolutiondesigns.com/images/freebies/city-wallpaper-47.jpg);
      border-bottom: 5px solid #fff;
      height: 600px;
      background-position: center;
      background-size: 100% 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-size: cover;
      line-height: 600px;
      text-align: center;
      width: 60vw;
      margin-left: -140px;
      z-index: 1;
position:absolute;
right:0;
      -webkit-transition: all .5s;
       -moz-transition: all .5s;
       transition: all .5s;
      opacity: .4;

    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <section id="aboutUs">
     <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>O nas</h1>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-7">
        <p class="desc wow bounceInLeft" data-wow-delay=".5s" data-wow-duration="1.2s">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur <b>adipisicing elit</b>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
         Ut enim ad minim veniam, <b>quis nostrud exercitation</b> ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
         Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum <b>dolore eu fugiat</b> nulla pariatur.
         Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in <b>culpa qui officia</b> deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline pull-right text-center wow bounceInLeft" data-wow-delay=".9s" data-wow-duration="1.2s">Czytaj więcej</a>
       </div>
       <div class="hidden-sm">
        <div class="aboutUsfoto wow bounceInRight" data-wow-delay=".2s" data-wow-duration="1.2s">
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </section>
```